# Creating multiple scopes for multiple instances using DI in dotnet core

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm currently trying to build a very basic system for dispatching events to multiple event handlers in a dotnet core application. I've got an interface for the handlers that looks something like this:

```
public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> {
    Task Handle(TEvent evt);
}
```

And on the other end of things I've got an interface for dispatching events.

```
public interface IEventDispatcher {
    Task Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent evt);
}
```

Let's assume an event that looks something like this:

```
public class FooEvent {
    ...
}
```

And two handlers that subscribe to this event

```
public class BarHandler : IEventHandler<FooEvent> 
{
    Task Handle(FooEvent evt) {
        ...
    }
}
public class BazHandler : IEventHandler<FooEvent> 
{
    Task Handle(FooEvent evt) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The part I'm struggling with is related to dispatching these events to all of the handlers. A straight forward implementation could look something like this, for clarity I'm executing the handlers sequentially and ignoring error handling here:

```
public class EventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher {
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

   public EventDispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }

   Task Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent evt) {
       foreach(var handler in _serviceProvider.GetServices<IEventHandler<TEvent>>()) {
           await handler.Handle(evt);
       }
   }
}
```

Finally, it's time for the real issue at hand, I want each of the handlers to have their own separate scope. Creating a shared scope for them could simply be done like this:

```
Task Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent evt) {
    using(var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope()) {
        foreach(var handler in scope.ServiceProvider
                                    .GetServices<IEventHandler<TEvent>>()) {
            await handler.Handle(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Put simply, how can I provide each of the handlers with their own scope?

Comment: I would say the lifetime of a scope here would be tied to the lifetime of an event which might be quite difficult to realise depending on the project type and your logic. Somehow, your broker that manages your dispatchers and handlers would be the one to own the scope. One point though, you should need to manipulate `IServiceProvider` only to create the scope then create the broker out of it and that's it (don't forget to dispose the scope too later on). Otherwise you will go further down the path of the service locator anti-pattern, if you care that is.